# Registry Writing not working

Tags: c#, registry

Here's my registry writing code

```
key.SetValue(KeyName, KeyValue_number, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

When debugging the values are like this:

```
key = {HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Test}
KeyName = "quack"
KeyValue_number = 1
```

So it seems like it should be inserting fine but i can't find the key in the registry at all :/, not as a directory or key
restarted regedit and everything, still nothing, it's confusing

Comment: Does the account used to execute the program have permissions to write to the registry?

Comment: From what you wrote I understand the code seems to be executed just fine, but you just can't see the change in the registry? No Exceptions?

Comment: Alright I've been looking for an hour, and right after i post this I figure it out.
Because i'm on a 64 bit system it decides to be difficult and auto-redirect my key to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Test instead.

Comment: You should post this as an answer and accept it so that other people who have your problem can see the solution easially :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that on a 64 bit system, windows automatically redirects a lot of keys to a different folder within the registry.
In my case it was "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Test".

EDIT: Thanks to Hans Passant below, apparently the way to fix this is to simply set your compiling platform to "Any CPU" and this problem is resolved

Comment: Suggests the bit of code you are using to write the reg entry is 32 bit. As long as all the other code that uses it is also 32 bit, then this isn't a problem. If 64 bit code needs to access the same key, then you need a 64 bit detect sizeof(int) == 8 will do for this case and then force it to go to the Wow6432Node.

Comment: I'm supposed to have everything through the normal "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Test" on any computer that uses the application, Still no clue how to do that though :/

Comment: Project + Properties, Build tab, change "Platform target" to AnyCPU.

Comment: You're.. kidding .. I was looking forever on how to fix this and it's that simple... That's painful :P But thanks ^^ it seems to work now

Comment: Damn I assumed at least one of the apps was forced to 32 bit (e.g. a legacy win32 app). Saying that, a wee registry helper static class sorts it out, as long as you remember to use it. :(